# MongoDB collection/Express.js for "friend request" functionality

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have an idea for how to store the relationships. Each user has a `friends` Array filled with IDs. However, how should I initiate a friend request in my Express.js app in MongoDB?

I'm thinking about creating a "notifications" collection with:

`_id, userId, type, friendId, read`

So when the requested friend logs in, they can see all of their own notifications to deal with...

Or is that ridiculous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds reasonable enough. But my approach will be a little different. I would store the notifications in the user db itself. Something like

```
username
dob
...
notifications[[type: 'friend', read: 0, request_from: '22sd300sdf45003425asz'], ...]
...
```

This way, you don't have to make a db call on every page load. As soon as you initialize a session (I use passport), it will be there, ready already for templates. After a valid action from the user, I can delete it or whatever.

But again, its dependent on the need. Do what suits you best!

Comment: Was also thinking of this!

How do I mock that up in the schema?

`var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  interests: Array,
  email: String,
  avatar: String,
  friends: Array,
  notifications: Array ? // an array of objects?
});`

Comment: Check the first code-block (last 5 lines): http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html :)

Answer (score 1):

For such notifications what I did, is as follows:

```
var notificationSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    to:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    },
    from:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'
    },
    for: {
        type: String
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: "Not Seen"
    },
    description:{
        type: String
    }
},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' }
});
```

where I have saved _id of to and from (users) where I used `for` field for notification type like following, liked etc and used `description` field as optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you store it in the user passport session (solution mentioned earlier) you will not be able to receive anymore notifications since it is static information in the header and not connected directly to the document store.

The best way to do it would to have let it have it's own store.

```
{Id:ObjectId, for_user:String,  sent from:String, status:Boolean}
```

Perhaps you can initially set the status to null then set it to true or false when a user accepts or denies it. After create the user to user friend relationship. That's more or less the way I would go about it.